# React-native fetch extremely slow on wifi compared to cellular. Both in dev and production, irrespective of running/not debugger

Tags: ios, react-native, fetch, wifi

I am facing extremely slow fetch/network on a RN 0.57 app with wifi (this has been the case since 0.4x, so i think it is version independent) 
I am fetching some json or downloading images with RNFS.

It happens on ios.

It happens on dev and release versions both.

It happens both when debugger is on/off.

**It does not happen on cellular.**

It happens both when using fetch, xmlhttprequest, (RNFS, i don't what that one uses)

It always happens on a wifi connection. (tried several networks/places)

The request takes 10-15seconds on wifi vs sub 1 second on cellular.

While not being sure, the delay partly comes from starting of the request,  several seconds pass until i get first event from xmlhttp.

I am stuck and cannot find a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after moving from ios 11 to 12